# Copy Paste two lines below Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA beginner and therefor, the following query might be very easy for you, but I can’t make it

What I am trying to is the following:

Build a macro with

1. Input with Date and Credit Rating on one sheet (existing) and
2. copy and paste it into a predefined table and
3. everytime you enter new data into the input field and click the macro button, the macro should copy and paste it into the table again, BUT two lines below the last cell/row used.
4. have a chart reading the data of the range, where the data are pasted to and automatically adjusts its range to the newly pasted values.

I hope, that I’ve explained my problem good enough, so that you can help.

```
Dim x As Integer 
Worksheets("Input").Range("D6:D7").Copy 
x = 2 
Do 
  x = x + 2 
  Worksheets("Chart").Range("B" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,Transpose:=True, xlPasteValues 
Loop Until x = 56 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Start something first, show code that doesn't work, and we'll help you make it work.

Comment: This only pastes my input values multiple times, every second row until the end of the loop. however, what i want is to add the new input values every click on the button two lines below the last ones: 
[code]Dim x As Integer
Worksheets("Input").Range("D6:D7").Copy
x = 2
    Do
        x = x + 2
        Worksheets("Chart").Range("B" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,Transpose:=True, xlPasteValues
    Loop Until x = 56
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub[code]

Comment: I put this code in your question for now, but in the future, code is easier to read in the post.  As you can see, it is not readable in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyTowRowsbelow()

Dim x As Long

Worksheets("Input").Range("D6:D7").Copy

With Worksheets("Chart")
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ' find last row in column B
    .Range("B" & x + 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True ' Paste the value 2 rows below the last cel with data
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: hi shai rado. thanks for your comment. I think you misunderstood, I do not want to find the last row of the column but the last row in the column with a value in it and then paste the next value in the second next line.

Comment: @jules_05 this is exactly what my code, it finds the last row in column B with value in it (did you test my code above?)

Comment: I did. Thank you. 

My probelm is, that my target sheeet, where the values are put, have values in every second row. the values from the input should then be posted (with every click on the button) in the second next line beginning at B2:C2, then by the next click on the button B4:C4, then B6:C6 etc...
Thanks in advance..

Comment: no, unfortunately not. it posts the value pair at the very end of my table. this is because my table ALREADY has values in it and i wanna let the values being put in the rows in between. do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

I find copy pasting to generally be a bad practice as it uses the system clipboard and could erase data that the user had in the clipboard.  Instead i try to explicitly set destination values.  This code should work if you paste it into the code module of your Input sheet.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'this built in subroutine in excel executes whenever something is changed on the worksheet
'we'll use this subroutine to determine range "D6:D7" was part of the sheet that was changed

'declare the range we want to detect if a change occurred, we'll just monitor range D7
Dim rangeMonitorForChange As Range
Set rangeMonitorForChange = Worksheets("Input").Range("D7")

'if the range changed on the sheet and the range were monitoring overlap/intersect then we'll call the method to upadte the chart sheet
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rangeMonitorForChange) Is Nothing Then
      copyDown
  End If
End Sub


Sub copyDown()
'define where to "copy" from
Dim rngSource As Range
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Input").Range("D6:D7")

'find the row we're going to "paste" to
Dim destRow As Long
destRow = Sheets("Chart").Range("B" & Sheets("Chart").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2

'define "paste" destination
Dim rngDest As Range
Set rngDest = Sheets("Chart").Range("B" & destRow & ":B" & destRow + 1)

'"paste" the values in
rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks perposterer, i'll give it a try and let you know asap.

Comment: this code doesn't work for me, because the values are pasted at the very bottom of my table (see explanation in my below comment) and those values are not transposed. do you get my problem?